# how can I run a .exe file through C++?

Tags: c++, exe, runtime-error

My .exe application needs to be opened in console window. Then I have to type the name of a `.txt` in the console application for it to read. How can I perform all these within my code at once?
I used to be able to run it (and not making it to read .txt) with `system("name.exe")`, but suddenly it gives,

> error: input "name.exe" is not a valid windows application

Comment: Have you checked the path of `"name.exe"` while opening with `system ()` function ?

Comment: Can you run `name.exe` by itself outside your other program?

Comment: Sounds like it's not in your [path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) anymore - see that link, and make sure `name.exe` is in a directory in the path.

Comment: Ok, Now I fixed the problem with using system("name.exe"), there was a problem with my .exe application. so my code opens the .exe application now ( I have set it to be done with a mouse click), the the following procedure has to be performed inside the console with       the same first mouse click:  1- type "name.txt" 2- press enter 3- type name2.exe 4- Press enter. How can I do that through my c++ code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your application read the filename as a command-line parameter, then you can run your application using system("name.exe name.txt").

Comment: I can not alter the application. It only gets two .txt files as an input ( the user have to type the name of each .txt file and press enter to run that application) I want all these to be done once I call the application through my c++ code. ( the name of .txt files are known)

Answer (score 0):

> 1- type "name.txt" 2- press enter 3- type name2.exe 4- Press enter. How can I do that through my c++ code?

```
std::string appName, fileName
std::cin >> appName >> fileName;
system(std::string(appName + " " + filename).c_str())
```

If names contain spaces, you might need to use `getline` to read them instead of `>>`.

--EDIT--

> Basically I want once my application is called the input is also automatically given to it.

[Creating Child process with redirected input (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[_popen documentation(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[pipe to subprocess (GNU)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html#Pipe-to-a-Subprocess)

Comment: It did not work that way. Basically I want once my application is called the input is also automatically given to it. once the application is called it will ask " type the name of your first file and press enter" and once that is done, it asks: " type the name of your second file and press enter".

Answer (score 0):

In Windows use the *CreateProcess* API to do this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx.
Do not use *system*.

Comment: What is missing is why not to use system: The behavior and return value of system are platform-dependent. That being said the CreateProcess API must be wrapped if the code shall be platform independent.